# Getting nothing while calling performClick() function - Android

Tags: java, android, xml, function

I'm new to Android developing and now I'm trying to simulate click on my **AutoCompleteTextView** object.
I'm expecting default android's keyboard appearance with the possibility to type something at the element

**Here is a simple function, where I'm trying to perform it:**

```
private void someTestMethodName() {
    AutoCompleteTextView tagSearchInput = findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);
    tagSearchInput.performClick();
}
```

**And here is .xml element defining:**

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="188dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="108dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="292dp"/>
```

Comment: How do you call `someTestMethodName` ?

Comment: @BartFriederichs, It starts from  "onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)" fuction, as I'm using Google Maps API

Comment: Are you certain it is fired?

Comment: @Zoe, Got it, thank you for advice!

Comment: @BartFriederichs, what do you mean?

Comment: @BartFriederichs, I thing you've meant if this method, where I'm performing an action is triggered. If so, my answer is - yes, of course, I have been debugging it for two days and trying to find an answer.

Comment: Have you tried to just have it steal focus instead clicking it?

Comment: @BartFriederichs, I'm not sure how to do it correctly, but I think the issue is hiding at ''focus'' stuff. I think I should read more documentation of it before using! Thank you for your answers!

Comment: I build the same functionality, and have it as well. I think it is not the `click` that shows the soft keyboard, but some other event or OS option.

Comment: That is a reasonable idea. I had fixated on this opinion and didn't see other ways to check it. Thank you so much, @BartFriederichs, I am going to dig this way

Comment: Check my answer ;-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `performClick` on a `TextView` does not pop up the soft keyboard, but you can quite easily do that yourself:

```
private void someTestMethodName() {
    AutoCompleteTextView tagSearchInput = findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);
    showSoftKeyboard(tagSearchInput);
}

public void showSoftKeyboard(View view){
    if(view.requestFocus()){
        InputMethodManager imm =(InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(view,InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    }
}
```

More information can be found here: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Working-with-the-Soft-Keyboard

Comment: Yeah, the main problem was I haven't read documentation to the end, so I've literally spent 2 days trying to figure out why performClick() doesn't work for me. It was working, but not that way I've thought. It is a good lesson for me.

Comment: That happens sometimes. Be careful though with this kind of functionalities, because your app may do weird things of people have a hardware keyboard connected. That is probably why `performClick` doesn't show the soft keyboard also.

Answer (score 0):

i never used performClick, you cant use setOnClickListener to catch a click

```
tagSearchInput.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //do somthing
        }
    });
```

Comment: This doesn't simulate a click, just catches one.

Comment: Yeap, but at the  same time this element has already got default event- when I'm clicking on it manually(while debugging) it performs by an appearance of the android keyboard, so I can start to type something